# random number generation in C++ ... first number not very random

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to get a uniform random number between 0 and 1 in C++ without using boost.  I do not want to depend on the library.

Whenever I start my program, I seed with:
    srand( time(NULL) );

Then I print 8 random numbers.  I separate different runs of the program with a blank line:

```
Random number: 0.226063
Random number: 0.449186
Random number: 0.474514
Random number: 0.160779
Random number: 0.220868
Random number: 0.136685
Random number: 0.260120
Random number: 0.843334

Random number: 0.226181
Random number: 0.422253
Random number: 0.808594
Random number: 0.040531
Random number: 0.212377
Random number: 0.421073
Random number: 0.965790
Random number: 0.026305

Random number: 0.226306
Random number: 0.526858
Random number: 0.898279
Random number: 0.378934
Random number: 0.736653
Random number: 0.924420
Random number: 0.718503
Random number: 0.888140

Random number: 0.226463
Random number: 0.157614
Random number: 0.010386
Random number: 0.551936
Random number: 0.391998
Random number: 0.303603
Random number: 0.659396
Random number: 0.465434
```

Why is the first number almost exactly the same every time?  I don't get it.  Should I toss the first number out or something?

---

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  srand( time(NULL) );
  printf("%f\n", (float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
  printf("%f\n", (float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
  printf("%f\n", (float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
  printf("%f\n", (float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
  printf("%f\n", (float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
  printf("%f\n", (float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
  printf("%f\n", (float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
  printf("%f\n", (float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
}
```

Comment: *Should I toss the first number out or something?* Apparently yes.

Comment: Can you provide a complete code listing of how you're generating your values.

Comment: If you're aware of a solution in an open source library, but you don't want to use that library, you can always copy that library's solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that two time samples close together will have similar values.  The RNG, when seeded, convolves the seed, but, depending on the RNG algorithm, it may not achieve full randomness for 2-3 cycles.  It's probably best to discard a few numbers (a random number of discards is ideal) in order to create optimal randomness.

Comment: If you don't trust the RNG, there's no reason you can't write your own, based on a published algorithm.  Some of the older "standard" RNGs are notoriously poor.

Comment: What implementation (compiler, runtime library, OS)?

Comment: Your OS may have a much better PRNG than your compiler. I'd look at what's there. There are some good PRNGs in Windows, for example.

Comment: Humans are horrible with random, do not trust your instincts (pull out your local maths professor and let him explain). As long as you wait 1 second between runs it works fine.

Comment: I have the same problem! For me, the first number is always 0.422xxx..., after editing and recompiling, I get 0.455xxx...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, *don't* throw out the first one. That skews the results. The sequence `{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}` is *exactly* as likely to appear as any other arbitrary seven-number sequence despite the propensity of humans trying to find meaning in everything :-)

Trying to fiddle with it because you don't like the sequence makes the random number generation *worse,* not better.

For what it's worth, you should make sure that your runs are at least a second apart so you don't use the same seed (that doesn't appear to be the case here). Other than that, use the results that the PRNG gives you *as-is* or find a better generator.

Either you're a statistician/cryptographer where you wouldn't be *using* a normal random function, or *it really doesn't matter!* For the *vast* majority of situations, it's the latter.

---

If you don't want a fancy one (or one involving a large amount of extra stuff) and you're just not happy with the one provided with your implementation, it's easy to implement one based on the `gcc` version, something like:

```
seed = (1103515245 * seed + 12345) & 0xffffffff
return seed & 0x7fffffff
```

And keep in mind the initial seed value is calculated on the argument supplied to `srand` with a modulus of `231-1` to minimise the sequence having a linear dependence on the initial seed (there's still linearity for the sequence, just not from the initial seed value).

The following code may make your life easier if you're just looking for a quick solution without depending on external libraries or spending time implementing the more complex generators:

```
// Assume 32-bit integer.
static int seed = 1;
void mySRand (int newseed) {
    seed = newseed % 0x7fffffff;
}
int myRand() {
    seed = 1103515245 * seed + 12345;
    return seed & 0x7fffffff;
}
```

---

The following program will actually give you an idea as to what that algorithm will do with small changes to the seed value provided to `mySRand`.

It gets the initial seed from `time (NULL)` then shows you what the initial values are out of `myRand` for twenty sequential seed values, along with the percentage changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

static int seed = 1;
void mySRand (int newseed) { seed = newseed % 0x7fffffff; }
int myRand() { seed = 1103515245 * seed + 12345; return seed & 0x7fffffff; }

int main (void) {
    int i, xyzzy, val, lastVal;
    double avg, diff;
    xyzzy = time (NULL);
    mySRand (xyzzy);
    lastVal = myRand();
    printf ("seed=%d, val=%12d\n", xyzzy, lastVal);
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        mySRand (++xyzzy);
        val = myRand();
        avg = val; avg = (avg + lastVal) / 2;
        diff = 100 * fabs (avg - val) / avg;
        printf ("seed=%d, val=%12d, avg=%12.1f, %%chg=%f\n",
            xyzzy, val, avg, diff);
        lastVal = val;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The percentage changes are based on the difference between the current value and the average between the current and the previous so as to hopefully not introduce bias. Sample output is:

```
seed=1324533721, val=  1092183454
seed=1324533722, val=    48215051, avg= 570199252.5, %chg=91.544175
seed=1324533723, val=  1151730296, avg= 599972673.5, %chg=91.963792
seed=1324533724, val=   107761893, avg= 629746094.5, %chg=82.888041
seed=1324533725, val=  1211277138, avg= 659519515.5, %chg=83.660545
seed=1324533726, val=   167308735, avg= 689292936.5, %chg=75.727484
seed=1324533727, val=  1270823980, avg= 719066357.5, %chg=76.732504
seed=1324533728, val=   226855577, avg= 748839778.5, %chg=69.705726
seed=1324533729, val=  1330370822, avg= 778613199.5, %chg=70.864150
seed=1324533730, val=   286402419, avg= 808386620.5, %chg=64.571108
seed=1324533731, val=  1389917664, avg= 838160041.5, %chg=65.829626
seed=1324533732, val=   345949261, avg= 867933462.5, %chg=60.141039
seed=1324533733, val=  1449464506, avg= 897706883.5, %chg=61.463005
seed=1324533734, val=   405496103, avg= 927480304.5, %chg=56.279815
seed=1324533735, val=  1509011348, avg= 957253725.5, %chg=57.639642
seed=1324533736, val=   465042945, avg= 987027146.5, %chg=52.884483
seed=1324533737, val=  1568558190, avg=1016800567.5, %chg=54.264095
seed=1324533738, val=   524589787, avg=1046573988.5, %chg=49.875518
seed=1324533739, val=  1628105032, avg=1076347409.5, %chg=51.262038
seed=1324533740, val=   584136629, avg=1106120830.5, %chg=47.190523
seed=1324533741, val=  1687651874, avg=1135894251.5, %chg=48.574735
```

so you can see there's actually a large difference in starting values based on initial seeds that are close together.

Comment: In theory yes, in practice unfortunately not. If you had a true source of random numbers (as opposed to **pseudo** random numbers) than I would totally agree with your statement.

Comment: I disagree.  In this particular case, it appears that the implementation's `rand()` has some problems, in that the first generated number is too predictably related to the seed value.  Discarding the first result probably does make sense.  Finding a better random number generator could make even more sense.

Comment: @paxdiablo: That is a very incorrect and dellusional comparison. How does someone get 177k with answers like that?  At best all you can do is compute the hamming distance.

Comment: @Jared, I got to 177k by getting far more upvotes than downvotes :-) If you think the answer is unhelpful, vote it down. That's how SO works. At the moment, it's +5/-1 so obviously more people think it's useful than those who think otherwise. If I have answers whose net votes are negative after a couple of weeks, I delete them, since the community has deemd them inadequate. What I _don't_ do is delete answers based on the comments of one person. However, I often change an answer if one or more people _convince_ me of its deficiencies.

Comment: [On wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use) is stated that GCC uses 31bits for modulo (maybe it has something to do with signed integer) and returns only 30bits, so shouldn't be those values: `0x7fffffff` and `0x3fffffff` ? And also I searched (for comparation) for some generated samples (first few numbers) on internet with some seed and LCG parameters, but found nothing. Is there any page with generated numbers for example for multiplier `1103515245` * seed (e.g.0) + increment `12345` ?

Comment: instead of this headache you could just throw away the first "bad" number

Comment: @mondlos, a generator that has a fault as serious as the first number being much the same may well have *other* problems. Me, I'd prefer to use a less problematic one, either a properly analysed LCG or even a more suitable one (like a Mersenne Twister).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the standard library, which provides both high-quality PRNG engines as well as the appropriate distribution adapters:

```
#include <random>

typedef std::mt19937 rng_type;
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> u01dist;

rng_type rng;

int main()
{
  rng.seed(std::time(NULL));

  double random_number = u01dist(rng);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: is this limited to a specific version of C++? r.cpp:4: error: ‘mt19937’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type

Comment: @gnychis, I think it's the stuff they added in TR1 of C++03. TR1 itself wasn't a standard, rather a guide for extensions, but I'm pretty certain it made its way into C++11. Your particular compiler may not support that standard or it may need flags to enable it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Extensible_random_number_facility or some detail.

Comment: You should add `-std=c++0x` to your GCC. In older versions, you may have to use `<tr1/random>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly normal. PRNG's must be *warmed up*. The number I have in the back of my head is something about 1000. That means, after seeding your PRNG, get 1000 numbers and throw them away.

The reason is how most generators are implemented. They are typically something like `x = a*x+b`, where `a` and `b` are constants. So, if you're unlucky, your seeds (which are in your case pretty close!) are chosen so that the first part of the equation does not have much relevance to the outcome (i.e. close to 0 (mod MAX_RAND)). That's why you have to warm up: It irons the similarity of your chosen seeds out. It sounds stupid, but that's how PRNG's work (you might get away with throwing out 50 instead of 1000, YMMV).

---

Btw., using `rand` is a terrible idea in general. Not only that (for reasons that honestly escape me) it is quite slow compared to other PRNG's, also the numbers it generates are quite poor (in terms of entropy, periodicity and so forth). If you don't want to use boost, maybe you can use gsl which has pretty much everything you could need (regarding random numbers).

Comment: That's only likely if your PRNG is brain-dead. The `a` term should be more than large enough so that small differences in initial seed make a large difference in initial value.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Besides the notion that `rand` **is** pretty brain-dead, I totally see that the explanation with the `a*x` term is quite weak, but that's the best understanding I got about the matter so far. There is probably a more convincing way to explain it, I agree.

Comment: If you examine a decent LC generator (GNU's a=1103515245, c=12345, seed_modulus=32bits, output=lower 30 bits), the seeds 27 and 28 (picked at random) results in the two outputs 803894712 and 833668133, a spread of about 3%. That's not _massive_ but it's enough to be decently random. My point either you need a really good RNG (in which case, get one) or you just use the one you have, which is usually more than adequate for those who don't need a real one :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Sure, by why would you live with a potentially horrible PRN sequence, when you can enhance the quality of your generator with minimal effort?

Comment: @bitmask I'm pretty sure in this case with a poor PRNG "warming up" only gives the *illusion* of being better, and with a good PRNG it doesn't matter.

Comment: My apologies to glibc, it actually uses the lower _31_ (not 30) bits so the 27/28 seed gives you 1877636536/833668133, a difference of _way_ more than 3%.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the delay between program executions is too short, thus the time function may be returning seeds that are too similar to each other.

It is hard to be sure without knowing how the srand function is implemented, but it is a pseudo-random generator, it will output the same sequence for the same seed for multiple executions. Try to feed seeds with a larger delay betweem each other, or add a variable padding to the time returned by the time function, and see if this affects the output enough. However, be aware that they are not real random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

When I slightly tweaked your sample to run when compiled as C (I don't know C++ well enough to fix the compile errors without cursing) I saw nothing but random-looking first lines:

```
$ while true ; do sleep 1 ; ./rand | head -1 ; done
0.493923
0.353780
0.217848
0.570592
0.430408
0.290481
0.651497
0.006394
0.865017
0.721335
0.581914
0.936602
0.796496
^C
```

Comment: I got something similar. Humans are very good at finding patterns when there is not one