# Why is the first result of rand() / double(RAND_MAX) is not random

Tags: c++, random

This is related to this question - [random number generation in C++ ... first number not very random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599238/random-number-generation-in-c-first-number-not-very-random)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

cout << rand() / double(RAND_MAX) << endl;
cout << rand() / double(RAND_MAX) << endl;
cout << rand() / double(RAND_MAX) << endl;
cout << rand() / double(RAND_MAX) << endl;
cout << rand() / double(RAND_MAX) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

If you run the binary (.exe) over and over again, you will notice that the first result always has the same first three numbers. E.g. 0.54xxxxx always for every run.

No, this isn't because I am spotting patterns where there aren't any. And waiting a few seconds between each run does not help either.

**Edit:** Only the 1st result has the first same three numbers. The rest are "random looking". Also, the generator is seeded with srand() (on the very first line of the code sample above).

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: GNU GCC Compiler (in Code Blocks 12.11).

Comment: version? cannot reproduce it with gcc 4.6.3. I saw similar stuff with MS vc, never with gcc.. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385541/c-predictable-rand-output

Comment: @simonc - the first three numbers are identical for the first result of every run. e.g. 0.54xxxx.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - version 4.7.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The randomness of `rand` isn't specified by the standard.  Most
generators will use the seed to initialize a static variable,
and calculate the next value from that, in a way that should
"appear" random (but is, of course, perfectly deterministic).
My guess is that the implementation on your machine returns the
old value of the static variable, which is equal to the seed the
first time through.  (This sort of surprises me, it's usual to
return the new value of the static.)

Anyway, it's a question of the quality of the implementation.
(I see the same thing with VC++11, but not with g++.)

EDIT:

Just a quick test to see how varying the seed affects the first
number returned:

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= 10; ++ i ) {
    std::srand( i );
    std::cout << i << ": " << std::rand() << std::endl;
}
```

The output with VC++11:

```
1: 41
2: 45
3: 48
4: 51
5: 54
6: 58
7: 61
8: 64
9: 68
10: 71
```

With g++ 4.7.2 (CygWin version):

```
1: 1481765933
2: 816048218
3: 150330503
4: 1632096437
5: 966378722
6: 300661007
7: 1782426941
8: 1116709226
9: 450991511
10: 1932757444
```

You say that you are seeing this with g++ under Code Blocks:
I can only guess that Code Blocks sets things up so that g++
uses the Microsoft libraries, rather that the GNU ones
(generally a better solution).

Anyway, the solution is simple: replace the single line you now
use to seed the generator with:

```
std::srand( std::time( NULL ) );
std::rand();        // throw out first value...
```

And if you need relatively good random numbers, drop `std::rand`
completely in favor of some of the more rigorously defined
generators in C++11.  (You can get them from Boost if you're not
using C++11.)

Comment: @alexbuisson It depends on what you're doing.  For simple games, it's probably good enough, especially if you skip the first couple of values.  Some earlier versions alternated between even and odd.  Which meant that two calls to `rand() % 6 + 1` to simulate throwing two dice could never turn up a 6 or an 8.  I don't think that it's quite that bad today.  Of course, if you do need reasonably good quality: that's why C++11 adds new, more rigorously specified generators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the long explanation. +1 and accepted.

Comment: I tried your test and I got the exact same output as what you got for VC++11!

Comment: @Legendre Well, it's a library issue, rather than a compiler.  My g++ is the CygWin version (under Windows---at home, I run Linux), which, knowing CygWin, probably uses the GNU version of the standard library.  My guess is that Code Blocks sets things up so that g++ uses the some Windows standard library (although I don't think that there is an equivalent to `libc.so` bundled with Windows).

Comment: Thanks for helping me get to the bottom of this.

Comment: The default installation of [codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26#windows) on Windows use [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW), which inherently use MS libraries